# ggplot2 - Factor Specific Styling

Tags: r, graph, graphics, ggplot2, dataframe

This seems like a very simple question so I'm very sorry if I'm repeating someone here. Haven't been able to find the answer so far!

I have a dataframe that looks something like:

```
country <- c("Denmark", "Denmark", "Ireland", "Ireland", "UK", "UK")
year <- c(2007, 2008, 2007, 2008, 2007, 2008)
share <- c(0.5, 0.52, 0.6, 0.72, 0.3, 0.2)
oecd <- data.frame(country, year, share)
```

(although a lot bigger) and I have a graph made in ggplot2:

```
q <- ggplot(data=subset(oecd, year >2003 & year < 2013),
            aes(year, share, colour = country)) +
geom_line() +
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
ylab("Share of Total Revenue")
```

which is fine but I'd like to be able to manipulate the graph by factor (eg make the Ireland line bigger, thicker, dashed differently, coloured green etc). I have tried this:

```
alpha <- ggplot(data=subset(oecd, year >2003 & year < 2013), aes(x=year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = share), data = subset(oecd, country == "Ireland"), size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = share), data = subset(oecd, country != "Ireland"), size = 1.5)
```

which works well enough for the Ireland line but not for the others. In my real dataset I have 12 factors so obviously don't want to subset every single country, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Use manual scales. See `help("scale_color_manual")` for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. If you want to change linetypes, colours and size dependent on `country`, then it's easiest to mention this when calling `ggplot`. Different linetypes, colours and sizes will be produced automatically. Specific linetypes, sizes etc. can be chosen using manual scales.

```
ggplot(data=subset(oecd, year >2003 & year < 2013),
  aes(year, share, colour=country, linetype=country, size=country)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(2,4,2)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,2,1)) +
  ylab("Share of Total Revenue")
```

Here manual scales for size and linetype are specified. The factor `country` has levels Denmark, Ireland and UK (in that order). So the vector `c(2,4,2)` assigns a thicker line to Ireland. In the same way, the manual scale for linetypes assings continuous lines to Denmark and the UK, and a dashed line (`2`) to Ireland.

Hope this helps. Cheers!